# Generate class names with fractional numbers

Tags: css, less

I want to create a classes as .rating-1-1{}, .rating-1-2{}, till 10.0 . Here 1-1 means it is 1.1. Where i want to replace decimal point with - . In my current implementation it generates as .rating-1.1, .rating-1.2 this class will not work to apply the css style.

Try code

```
@iterations: 10;
.rate-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    .rate-@{i} {
        width: percentage((@i / @iterations));
    }
    .rate-loop(@i - 0.1);
}
.rate-loop (@iterations);
```

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple arithmetics and [numeric functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions), e.g.:

```
.loop(3);
.loop (@n, @j: @n) when (@j > 0) {
    .loop(@j, @j - 1/10);
    @i: floor(@j);            // integer part
    @f: floor(mod(@j, 1)*10); // fractional part
    .foo-@{i}-@{f} {
        width: 10% * @j;
    }
}
```

this will generate classes from `foo-0-0` to `foo-3-0`.

[*Demo*](//lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.loop(3)%3B%5Cn.loop%20(%40n%2C%20%40j%3A%20%40n)%20when%20(%40j%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.loop(%40j%2C%20%40j%20-%201%2F10)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40i%3A%20floor(%40j)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20integer%20part%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40f%3A%20floor(mod(%40j%2C%201)*10)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fractional%20part%5Cn%20%20%20%20.foo-%40%7Bi%7D-%40%7Bf%7D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%2010%25%20*%20%40j%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

---

When numeric conversion are not applicable use [`replace`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-replace)